# How can I display a path (string) as directory lister?

Tags: php

I have some paths as strings (These folders do not exist, there is only the sting). For example:

```
Volumes/data/films/godfather/godfather.mov

Volumes/data/serials/simpsons/season1/episode1.mov

Volumes/data/serials/simpsons/season1/episode2.mov
```

I want to display these paths as directories and files like in this demo http://demo.directorylister.com

I can find a lot tutorials about how to display ftp directories. But I really find nothing about displaying string paths as folders. I am grateful for any hint or any idea. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please try something yourself and if you have problems ask a new question..

Comment: @MateiMihai. Thank you, I will try. By the way, your profile description is very cool!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use CSS to style the folders to diplay in a directory kind of style.
And if you see their URL when you click on a particular directory, its like `http://demo.directorylister.com/?dir=software`. This means, they are taking the dir as an argument, and then displaying contents that are in the `dir`. So, you need to store these data in database, and get it with some query like `select * from files_dirs where parent_dir = software`, you can then display the result in another page and so on. Hope this helps, Comment for clarification.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just try to do not store the data again into the database.

Comment: Welcome, from what I see, every page displays the result of a query which asks for the files contained in a particular folder which you can get from the parameter in the URL. In the end it all comes down to how you structure the database for this.

Comment: I will give it a try and post later my result